# Simplify Mathematical Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, summation

Can someone help me to simplify the following expression? I can assume b is small and $0<b<1$.
$(C^{N}_{i})$ is the binomial coefficient.

$$A=[(1-b)^{N} + \sum^{N}_{i=1} (C^{N}_{i} - 2 C^{N-1}_{i-1})b^{i} (1-b)^{N-i}]$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$(1-b)^N + \sum_{i=1}^N C_i^N b^i \, (1-b)^{N-i}=\sum_{i=0}^N C_i^N b^i \, (1-b)^{N-i} = (b+1-b)^N= 1$$

so that

$$\begin{align}A &= 1-2 \sum_{i=1}^N C_{i-1}^{N-1} b^{i} \, (1-b)^{N-i}\\ &= 1 - 2 b \sum_{i-1=0}^{N-1} C_{i-1}^{N-1} b^{i-1}\, (1-b)^{N-1-(i-1)}\\ \therefore \; A &=1-2 b\end{align}$$

The sum in the next to last term being $1$.

Comment: Would you please explain the first line, or give me a hint? I am having trouble proving that the LHS equals 1.

Comment: @Orangutango: see my edit above